# Como generar folio con Sqlite android

Tags: android-sqlite

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Buenas

Tengo una duda, tengo una app que trabajo con datos almacenado en sqlite es una app de cobranza, ya tengo todo el funcionamiento de mi app, solo que me falta el poder generar folio que cuando el usuario aplique un pago le genere un folio interno, ¿se podrá con sqlite?

Comment: Que es exactamente un folio interno?

Comment: si mira. me refieron a que cuando yo aplique un pago de 200 me un folio por ejemplo si apenas es mi primer pago que me el folio 0001

Answer (score 1):

Si lo único que necesitas en mantener un contador puedes usar [shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) para mantener un valor entre sesiones de la aplicación.

Ten en cuenta que al igual que SQLite, **estos valores son locales** del dispositivo (los números de folios no serian únicos entre otros dispositivos corriendo la misma app) y que **esta información se elimina si el usuario limpia los datos de la app o la desinstala**.

En caso de querer salvar alguno de estos casos deberás guardar los valores en un servidor externo.

Comment: mira te agregue una imgen del folio que me entrega el webservices cuando trabajo con wifi en tiempo real

Comment: y eso es lo que mas o menos quiero que cuando se realice un cobro en modo desconectado me muestro un folio interno, solo que no se como generarlo...